# How can I override or add to the XPages NotesXspDocument events?

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control into which I pass a data source. The customecontrol.xsp-config file property:

```
<property>
  <description>The src Datasource source data (WIP)</description>
  <display-name>Source Datasource</display-name>
  <property-name>srcDatasource</property-name>
  <property-class>com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData</property-class>
  <property-extension>
    <required>true</required>
    <designer-extension>
      <category>1. Workflow Parameters</category>
      <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.dataSourcePicker</editor>
    </designer-extension>
  </property-extension>
</property>
```

I want to add some logic to the `querySaveDocument` of this data source with code in the custom control's `beforePageLoad` event. This logic will add a reader and author names items to the doc as well as some other control values.

How can I get my code added into this event?

Thanks in advance...

/Newbs

Answer (score 2):

You may find a solution here:

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/03/xpages-dynamically-binding-document.html

Credits to Tommy Valand...

Comment: This may have promise but not right out-of-the-box since it assumes the data source is configured at the view level. Most of ours (and there are usually more than one) are attached to panels in custom controls.. His comments suggest a way to do that but, that might take a while to code. That is for tomorrow at this point.

Comment: Sadly the code from Tommy requires that you use a fairly bad persistence setting: 'Looking at the code, it's possible that I ran it with "Keep all pages in memory" persistence/it won't run on any other persistence setting.' Makes it not usable...

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading about the computeWithForm property of an xpage. Which can be set to onload, onsave or both.

From Mastering Xpages book:

> For XPages Domino Document data sources, if *computeWithForm* is set, all fields specified in the form are appanded to the document that is being created. Any formulas used to caculate default values are executed and the results are stored in corresponding field.

Maybe it fits your needs

Edit:
Seems there is a bug look at this article:

> http://www.thenorth.com/apblog4.nsf/0/17B0E8334B2DCA68852579B400639D62

Not sure if it is fixed by ibm of if there is a workaround.

Edit2:
Not sure but this might help
[From Xsnippets.org](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events)

It is an [answer](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events) to another question.

Comment: There are so many issues with using Compute With Form, I do not know where to start, except to say, that in some cases, there is no form to compute with, and in others the forms are so complex with legacy code that there is no chance the form will compute

Comment: Since i myself am still in the process of learning everything about Xpages, and java, javascript i dont have an other option you could try. I was searching for a solution of a problem of myself when i noticed your post, after i just read the computewithform in the Mastering xpages book.
Hope someone will have the answer you need and post it.